# How to get distinct values based on one parameter?

Tags: teradata

I am using teradata to pull some staff

`select eventid, personid
.........
.......`

I need to `select` distinct values base ONLY on the eventid parameter, so the i want to apply `distinct` to eventid, and let personid be any kind of first value

How can i do this?

If i do

`select distinct eventid, personid
............
.........`
This will pull distinct based on both parameters

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have some preference regarding the returned value for `personid` (lowest/highest) you should use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
select * from tab 
qualify row_number() 
        over (partition by eventid 
              order by persionid) = 1;
```

Otherwise this avoids a sort and should thus use less resources:

```
select * from tab 
qualify sum(1) 
        over (partition by eventid 
              rows unbounded preceding) = 1;
```